# Data migration from source to target database SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two tables in SQL Server 2012.

- Table `tblSource` remains in SourceDB database and
- Table `tblTarget` remains in TargetDB database.

Both of the above tables remain at the same server.

So I want to transfer data from source to target table with this query:

```html
INSERT INTO TargetDB.dbo.tblTarget(ProductID, ProductName, CategoryName)
 SELECT 
        p.ProductID, p.ProductName, c.CategoryName
 FROM 
        dbo.tblProduct p
 LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.tblCategory c ON p.ProductID = c.ProductID
```

Here,

- I do not want to write `TargetDB.dbo.tblTarget`
- rather I would like to write following way during insert data to other database table `dbo.tblTarget`

But it does not work.

Error shows

> Invalid object name 'dbo.tblTarget'

How can I do this? Transferring data to target database without prefix db name from source db.

It is required because of I have to perform this operation in 3 servers, where database names are not same. **Is this possible?**

Answer (score 0):

I doubt whether its possible without mentioning `database` name;

When you say `dbo.tblTarget` the object will be  searched  in the database the `session pointed to`. 
If you want to look in other database then you have to mention the DB  name too. `TargetDB.dbo.tblTarget`.

You can use `dynamic sql` and `procedure`;

```
create procedure insert_data(
    @TargetDB as nvarchar(250) 
)
as
begin
    DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
    SET @SQLString = N'INSERT INTO '  +  @TargetDB +'.dbo.tblTarget(ProductID, ProductName, CategoryName)
    SELECT 
        p.ProductID, p.ProductName, c.CategoryName
    FROM  dbo.tblProduct p
    LEFT JOIN dbo.tblCategory c ON p.ProductID = c.ProductID'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
end;
go
```

create `procedure`in the `sourceDB`.
then execute the procedure with targetDB as the  in parameter.

```
exec   insert_data('targetDB1')
exec   insert_data('targetDB2')
exec   insert_data('targetDB3')....
```

Comment: That is why I'm asking about it. Is this possible or not? Otherwise I'll have to write same stored procedure  as per server.